# Cannot output Excel file to txt file using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

SO i am quite a beginner in C#, and am having a real issue with outputting a .txt file from an excel file that is being read into memory.The file successfully loads in the grid view i have placed, but it keeps going to the 'catch' routine and outputting the 'error' message box. Any ideas how to fix this issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace KTypeLookUp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    FileStream ostrm;
    StreamWriter writer;
    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//Select Input File Button
        String textPath = @"C:\\AAAtemp\\export.txt";
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xls)|*.xls|All Files|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {//Read and display Excel file
            string path = ofd.FileName.ToString();

            textBox3.Text = path;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
            (
                  "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn
            );
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            try
            {
                ostrm = new FileStream(textPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, failed to output error", "My Application",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {

                    Console.SetOut(writer);
                    Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
                writer.Close();
                ostrm.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Text file created", "My Application",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

            }
        }

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//Text box to display path
        textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this issue? Change `catch` to `catch (Exception ex)` and show `ex.ToString()` in your messagebox instead of an unhelpful "Failed to output"

Comment: Sweet jesus, upon adding that line it allocated the error. *DOH!* Many thanks GrawCube

Comment: No problem, remember to add an answer when you figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

As per GrawCube:

Any ideas how to fix this issue? Change catch to catch (Exception ex) and show ex.ToString() in your messagebox instead of an unhelpful "Failed to output"